# VS Code 起動時に求められるプロキシ認証ポップアップで認証を通過できないが、認証する方法はないか

Tags: windows, vscode

会社のPCでVS Code起動時にプロキシ認証を求められますが、何を入力してもOK押下時反応がないです。
何も入力せずOK押下した場合は「このフィールドを入力してください。」が表示されます。
Cancel押下時も反応がないです。

上記によって、pluginが使えないことに困っています。
別の方法でプロキシ認証を通過でき、pluginが使用できれば、このポップアップの挙動はどうでも良いです。

VS Codeを再インストールしてもだめでした。

ご回答よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: プロキシ認証のポップアップ]

Comment: settings.jsonにプロキシを設定していますか？

Comment: 認証が必要なことなら、管理部署に入力すべき情報を問い合わせるか申請するかして入手すれば良いのでは？ 設定ファイルで何とかなるにしても、入力すべき情報は必要でしょうし。そうではなくてNetworkへの接続は不要でオフラインで使いたいとか、イントラネット内だけ見れればよいとかなら、例えばこちらの記事の方法でインストール・設定し直すことになるのでは？ [Visual Studio CodeをオフラインPCで使用する](https://qiita.com/mekemeke421/items/98d5a3e2f2cc7517a6ab), [【VS Code】Internetの無い環境でRemote Development機能を使用する方法](https://www.mathkuro.com/vs-code/remote-development-in-offline/)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/97199

ここで認証画面が空になる問題が紹介されています。
再インストールしてだめなら`proxy.html`を一度削除して最新版をコピペしてはいかがでしょうか。